# .NET 8 Visual Studio/Rider Issue with .NET MAUI Publish Windows Build - RID Mismatches

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui, rider

### Issue with .NET MAUI Publish Windows Build - RID Mismatches

I am working on a .NET MAUI application and encountering issues during the publish build process. I am trying to side-load the application and create an installer file, but I'm running into Runtime Identifier (RID) mismatches.

When I try to publish, I receive the following error:

The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win10-x86' is not recognized.

However, my application does not seem to recognize the .NET 8 standard RIDs such as `win-x64`, `win-x86`, or `win-arm64`. I am looking for a solution that allows me to publish my application with the GUI in Visual Studio or Rider.

#### Current Configuration

Here is the screenshot of the MSIX Profiles available in my project:
[MSIXProfiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM50p.png)

#### Seeking Help

I am looking for guidance on how to resolve this RID mismatch issue and successfully publish my .NET MAUI application. Any suggestions or insights, especially regarding publishing through Visual Studio or Rider GUIs, would be greatly appreciated.

#### Steps Taken

1. **Checked the Target Frameworks**: Ensured the application targets the correct frameworks for .NET MAUI, verifying compatibility and consistency across the project.
2. **Updated the Project File**: Manually edited the `.csproj` file to explicitly define the Runtime Identifiers. Added `<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;win-x86;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>` within a `<PropertyGroup>` to align with .NET 8 standards.
3. **Used the Correct Publish Command**: Successfully published the application using CLI commands, specifying the RIDs with `-r win-x64`, `-r win-x86`, and `-r win-arm64`. This indicates that the CLI recognizes the RIDs correctly.
4. **MSIX Packaging Check**: Confirmed that the MSIX packaging project includes and correctly handles the specified RIDs, ensuring that the packaging process aligns with the targeted platforms.
5. **SDK and Tool Updates**: Updated to the latest .NET SDK and tooling to rule out any issues related to outdated software versions.
6. **NuGet Package Updates**: Performed a comprehensive update of all NuGet packages within the project to ensure compatibility and the latest features.
7. **Consulted Documentation**: Reviewed the latest .NET MAUI and .NET documentation, focusing on sections relevant to publishing and Runtime Identifier specifics.
8. **Project Clean and Rebuild**: Executed a clean and rebuild of the project to resolve any issues related to stale or corrupted build outputs.
9. **Installed MAUI Workload**: Ensured that the MAUI workload is properly installed and configured within the development environment.
10. **IDE-Specific Attempts**:

    - **Visual Studio 2022**: Attempted to publish the build using the GUI in Visual Studio 2022. Despite the correct configuration and updated environment, the IDE failed to produce a published build.
    - **JetBrains Rider 2023.3**: Similar attempt made using JetBrains Rider 2023.3. However, like Visual Studio, Rider also could not generate a published build through its GUI.

Despite these efforts, I am unable to use the GUIs of Visual Studio 2022 or JetBrains Rider 2023.3 for publishing, even though CLI commands work as expected. I am seeking insights into resolving this discrepancy and enabling successful GUI-based publishing.

Comment: See following to configure your project for Maui : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/configuration-management

Comment: @jdweng what you provided Is not relevant to the issue. I would love to get some feedback on something I can do to correct this issue or if it is a common problem for .NET MAUI

Comment: My link is the main page for Maui.  It is not clear on how you project is configures and what feature the failure is occurring on.  You did not include a trace stack which should always be included for a runtime issue.  On the left side of the link are more topics and at the top there are other links like examples.